# user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email,password)

Tags: django, testing, django-models, tdd

I am getting this error while executing .I have made a test models file to test my models using TDD.I could find the error i have also tried models.User.create_user but that also didnt work.

Here is my test_models.py
'''

```
class ModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_create_user_with_email_successful(self):
        """Test creating a new user with email"""
        email = 'hassansahi6464@gmail.com'
        password = 'admin'
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email=email, 
            password=password
        )
        

        self.assertEqual(user.email, email)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(password))

    def test_new_user_email_normalized(self):
        """Test the email for user is normalized"""
        email = 'hassansahi6464@GMAIL.COM'
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email,'admin')
        self.assertEqual(user.email,email.lower())
```

and here is my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager , AbstractBaseUser , BaseUserManager , PermissionsMixin
from django.db.models.base import Model

# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email) , **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)

        return user
        

class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin,Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

**Settings.py**

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

Comment: Add the parens: `objects = UserManager()`, so `UserManager()` not just `UserManager`

Comment: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user' . GETTING THIS ERROR

Answer (score 2):

Solved The problem by simply changing UserManager to UserManager() in models.py
objects = UserManager()